# android 4.4 simpledateformate parse error

Tags: android

I want to parse a string date using simpledateformate,but I got a wrong time in android 4.4 api

**here is my code**

```
    String notificationDateStr = "";
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSZ");
    try {
        Date notificationDate = dateFormat.parse(notificationTime);
        dateFormat.applyPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
        notificationDateStr = dateFormat.format(notificationDate);
        if (notificationDateStr.equals(dateFormat.format(new Date()))) {
            dateFormat.applyPattern("HH:mm");
            notificationDateStr = dateFormat.format(notificationDate);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
```

my data is 
2016-05-10T08:41:13.325679+00:00

2016-05-10T08:39:42.754822+00:00

2016-05-10T08:36:02.098456+00:00

2016-05-10T08:31:03.787253+00:00

but the result is

16:46

16:52

16:37

16:44

why for this? how I can adjust my time to right

add:

I use my code in android 6.0 api ,this is right

Comment: it's not very clear what is the right format for your needs

Comment: @visionixvisionix  if the time is today ,I want to get "HH:mm", if not ,I want to get "yyyy-MM-dd"

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String getOriginalTime() {

    String notificationDateStr = " 2016-05-10T08:41:13.325679+00:00";

    SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
    SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");

    Date date = null;
    String str = null;

    try {
        date = inputFormat.parse(notificationDateStr);
        str = outputFormat.format(date);

        Log.e("DATE****", str);
    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    return str;
}
```

Comment: can you tell me what was wrong with my code, the result for your code is right, but I have to new three simpledateformate , that is too much

Comment: you append ".ssssssZ" at last in DateFormat String, Just removed it...
If you happy with my answer just give vote.

Comment: but I want to get the timezone,how counld I do?

Comment: parse the ssssssZ in api 4.4 was wrong, but in api 6.0 is right. I found simpledateformate not support .ssssss in api 4.4, just supoort .sss

Comment: You can not get Timezone from Date,
You can get Timezone from Device...

`TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();
System.out.println("TimeZone   "+tz.getDisplayName(false, TimeZone.SHORT)+" Timezon id :: " +tz.getID());`

Comment: I want to get timezone of my data, not my current Device

Comment: parse the ssssssZ in api 4.4 was wrong, but in api 6.0 is right. I found simpledateformate not support .ssssss in api 4.4, just supoort .sss